# RAM 4GB to 8GB upgrade - not working

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have `ASUS P5G41T-M LE` motherboard and I run an old `Pentium Dual-Core E5700` processor on it. Until today I ran 4GB RAM on it, precisely two `KVR1333D3N9K2/4G` planks and everything was fine.

The [manufacturer's specs](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5G41TM_LE/specifications/) say I may use up to 8GB RAM on the motherboard, so today I bought one `KVR1333D3N9/8G` plank. When I put it in and start the PC, the fan starts rotating and I hear the HDD working, but no POST message - the screens stays black the whole time.

Someone told me the processor FSB value should be the same or higher than the RAM, but my `E5700` FSB is `800MHz` and it worked perfectly with the old `1333MHz` RAM.

### update

I also tried `KVR13N9S8K2/8` - 2x4GB planks - with same luck. No post message, nothing. I doubt both products are faulty. The only difference is `KVR1333D3N9` is in QVL.

Comment: 8GB will be 2x4GB maximum. Doubt one 8GB will be any good to you.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can live with one 8GB

Comment: If you insert just one of the 4GB KVR13N9S8K2 sticks, does it POST then? Did you try just using the original RAM again? Does it still POST?

Comment: Probably the motherboard needs to be filled with two planks in order to start. As mentioned by 'Techie007', try fill one 4GB RAM in the RAM slot bank and try booting it. If it is not working, then the motherboard spec would require two sticks inserted to start the system.

Comment: @VembuTech It doesn't need two sticks to boot, just needs 2 if you want Dual-channel. :)

Comment: If it still boots with the old RAM, and you havn't already, get the latest BIOS for that motherboard form Asus and flash it.  Newer BIOS versions may support newer memory configurations.

Comment: Also note, just because "KVR1333D3N9" is I the QVL, doesn't mean all capacities with that model number will work. The only KVR1333D3N9 that's actually listed is the 2GB variant (that you're currently using as the "old" RAM). ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the specs [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5G41TM_LE/specifications/) and [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/p5g41t-m-le), the maximum RAM size is 8GB, with 2 DIMM slots. What they don't tell you is what the maximum DIMM size *per slot* is.

In [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5G41T-M_LE/E5155_P5G41T-M_LE_manual.zip) though it states (pg 1-13):

> You may install 512MB, 1GB, 2GB, and 4GB unbuffered non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.

So it appears that the maximum stick size per slot is 4GB maximum.

That motherboard supports 4GB RAM X 2 for a total of 8G, it will not work with a single 8G stick of RAM.

Comment: Please include the source for where you are seeing/getting that info...

Comment: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5G41TM_LE/specifications/ and http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/p5g41t-m-le has the same info.

Comment: Yup, that's where I got mine [QVL](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5G41T-M/Memoy_QVL.zip) - plus I've never met a machine that can address its full spec on a single socket. Mine can take 64GB, but won't deal with more than 8GB per slot, across 8 slots. 16s just don't work.

Comment: Took us a while to get from my first 'seems obvious' hunch to a fully-qualified Answer, but we got there in the end +1 ;)

Comment: you're right, will return the plank and rather buy a new motherboard... and everything else :)